# Hierarchical Memory allocator library for C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, hierarchical

My application is mostly organised in *layers* so I found that something like the [APR memory pools](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group__apr__pools.html) would be the best way.

While reading on SO about `C++ placement new` posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362953/what-are-uses-of-the-c-construct-placement-new), and [a more generic C allocation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722922/best-way-to-handle-memory-allocation-in-c) I was thinking about hand-crafting a hierarchical pool allocator as suggested in one post, but in the pure NYI tradition **I'm first asking if something like this already exists.**

It could also have the nice property of being able to give back unused memory to the OS (since allocation could be done with `mmap(MAP_ANON)`) or could be [allocating from the stack](http://the-lazy-programmer.com/blog/?p=24) as suggested [Ferrucico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086/ferruccio) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362953/what-are-uses-of-the-c-construct-placement-new/363537#363537).

Comment: Let's ask something back. Is memory allocation a bottleneck in your application that has been proven by profiling? If not, why bother with custom allocators?

Comment: The hierarchical memory pools are helping also with correctness as you eliminate one source of memory leaks.

Comment: @florin If you use c++ correctly (containers, raii, ...) the chances of having leaks is really low. I can't even remember when I had to track the last leak. It's ages ago.

Comment: They don't help with "correctness", they pot a band-aid on incorrect code.

Comment: Actually the application is meant to temporarily allocate a dozen of megabytes and release them afterwards. So since I don't want keep then unused between 2 uses I thought first about mmap-ing some memory "by hand". But after reading a little here and there, I thought that having a nice API would be quite nice and promote reuse for this usage pattern. It's not meant to replace the *whole* allocation (RAII is quite nice for general use)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of another good hierarchical memory allocator, but it calls `malloc` underneath the covers.

> [talloc](http://talloc.samba.org/) is a hierarchical pool based memory allocator with destructors.  It is the core memory allocator used in Samba4, and has made a huge difference in many aspects of Samba4 development.
>
> To get started with talloc, I would recommend you read the [talloc guide](http://samba.org/ftp/unpacked/talloc/talloc_guide.txt).

That being said, Glibc's `malloc` already uses `mmap(MAP_ANON)` for allocation larger than `mmap_threshold`, which you can set via `mallopt(M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, bytes)`.  By default it is dynamically adjusted between

```
/*
  MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX and _MIN are the bounds on the dynamically
  adjusted MMAP_THRESHOLD.
*/

#ifndef DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MIN
#define DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MIN (128 * 1024)
#endif

#ifndef DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX
  /* For 32-bit platforms we cannot increase the maximum mmap
     threshold much because it is also the minimum value for the
     maximum heap size and its alignment.  Going above 512k (i.e., 1M
     for new heaps) wastes too much address space.  */
# if __WORDSIZE == 32
#  define DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX (512 * 1024)
# else
#  define DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX (4 * 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(long))
# endif
#endif
```

Watch out if you lower it; by default no more than `#define DEFAULT_MMAP_MAX 65536` pieces will be allocated using `mmap`.  This can be changed with `mallopt(M_MMAP_MAX, count)`, but using many `mmap`s has an overhead.

The environment variables `MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_` etc. will also set these options.

Obviously, memory that `malloc` allocates with `mmap` is freed with `munmap`.  I'm not sure if any of this is documented anywhere outside of Glibc's source code, or has any compatibility guarantees.

Comment: sizeof(talloc_chunk) is 88 bytes (2.0.8). each leaf in hierarchical structure has 88 bytes weight. this is impossible big deal

Answer (score 2):

Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/) has a carefully tuned single-pool allocator.  You could link them together to make a hierarchical allocator, which would be simpler than rolling your own from scratch.

You *do* have profiling results that show memory management is a significant bottleneck, right?  Or are you just trying to simplify the API for allocation?

Comment: Your second guess is correct, I just try to have a better API than hand crafting anonymous mmaps.

Comment: OK, in that case I like Hanson's API pretty well---worth checking out.